# Is there any way to show a "Select folder" only dialog on macos?

Tags: macos, electron, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to provide a functionality to export a bunch of documents in batch to a folder in a blazor app using electron. I use the following code to show a "Save as" dialog:

```
private async Task<string> _ShowSaveDialog(string title, string extensionName, string extension)
{
    var mainWindow = Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First();
    var options = new SaveDialogOptions
    {
        Title = title,
        Filters = new FileFilter[]
        {
            new FileFilter { Name = extensionName, 
                Extensions = new string[] {extension },
                
            }
        }
    };
    var filePath = await Electron.Dialog.ShowSaveDialogAsync(mainWindow, options);

    return filePath;
}
```

This shows something like this on macos:

[image]

This doesn't serve my purpose because I don't want to give a file name because I will generate them when exporting the documents in batch.

After reading all the electron documentation I haven't seen any way to accomplish this. Is this even possible? Isn't weird not having this kind of dialogs on macos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you likely want to use:
[dialog.showOpenDialog([browserWindow, ]options)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) with 'openDirectory' as one of the option properties. This means that only directories can be selected.

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
  properties: ['openDirectory']
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result.canceled)
  console.log(result.filePaths)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: I will mark it as correct. I'm using electron.net not elector.js, sorry I missespeled it wrong when adding the tags. But you put me on the right track. Thanks!